# In Chrome "Advanced Sync Settings..." dialogue, why are "Encryption Options" disabled?

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome Settings, if I select "Advanced Sync Settings..." a dialogue appears with "Encryption Options" disabled (image below). My reading of the documentation is that I should be able to make changes. Is this normal, and how can I change this setting?

[image: Advanced Sync Settings...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting your password will erase all your stored encrypted data.  You need to go to your Google account dashboard to do that. 
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035

Comment: But I don't want to change my password or reset my data. Are you saying that if I want to change my encryption options, then I have to go to the Dashboard and use the "Stop and Clear" button to turn Sync off, and if I do that then afterwards I'll be able to change the "Encryption Options".

Comment: Perhaps I should note that my goal is to use my Google credentials for Chrome Sync (note I am not syncing passwords)

Comment: The encryption options are disabled because you've already set them. To reset them you need to go to your Google account dashboard. "Once you encrypt all your synced data with your own passphrase, it's not possible to go back to only encrypting passwords without resetting sync."

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the explanation I was looking for.